# How to Convert date into dd.MM.yyyy format in C# from excel

Tags: c#, excel, date

In excel sheet i have date in format `dd.MM.yyyy` 16.10.2011 **(16 as dd, 10 as MM)**. When i'm importing data from excel to SQL Server 2008 i get `MM.dd.yyyy` but still 16.10.2011 **(16 as MM, 10 as dd)**. That's not correct. I found solution on this: go to SQL Server 2008 -> Security -> logins -> {user properties} -> and change default language for user. With this solution i get in SQL Server 2008 `dd.MM.yyyy` 16.10.2011 **(16 as dd, 10 as MM)**. Is there any other way to convert date in `dd.MM.yyyy` format without changing user language?

```
String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\JantarV7Export.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

olecon.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = olecon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT person_id, date_of_hours, number_of_hours FROM [Sheet1$]";                    
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
OleDbDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
conn.Open();
while (odr.Read())
{
    SqlCommand cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test_data values (newid(),'" + odr[0] + "',@date_of_hours,'" + odr[2] + "')";
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@date_of_hours", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =odr[1];
}
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
olecon.Close();
conn.Close();
```

I think that problem is when i'm inserting into `test_data` datatable. So i probably should convert dates somehow before inserting. What do you suggest? Thanks. Is there any options like this:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test_data values (newid(),'" + odr[0] + 
    "',CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@date_of_hours,104),'" + odr[2] + "')";
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@date_of_hours", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =odr[1];
```

(this doesn't work because of CONVERT in insert, but is there some similar solution) or

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@date_of_hours,104) AS [DD:MM:YYYY]
```

**UPDATE**
In other form i read data through combobox. It shows 1.10.2011, 2.10.2011, .... to 16.10.2011.

```
da_test_data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT test_data_id, date_of_hours, number_of_hours FROM test_data WHERE _person_id= '" + person_id_person + "' ORDER BY date_of_hours", conn);
dt_test_data = new DataTable();
da_test_data.Fill(dt_test_data);
cb_datum.DataSource = dt_test_data.DefaultView;
cb_datum.ValueMember = "test_data_id";
cb_datum.DisplayMember = "date_of_hours";
```

And combobox for **projects**:

```
 private void cb_datum_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      DataRowView drvProjekt = cb_datum.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
      if (drvProjekt != null)
      {
          string date1 = drvProjekt["date_of_hours"].ToString();  
          DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
          date2 =Convert.ToDateTime(date1);

          //DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "MMddyyyy hh:mm:ss", null);
          //DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

          //object obj = DateTime.ParseExact(dddd, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", null);
          conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
          conn.Open();

          da_projekt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT projekt_id, name_of_projekt, date_of_start, date_of_end FROM projekt WHERE date_of_start < '" + date2 + "' AND date_of_end > '" + date2 + "' ", conn);
          dt_projekt = new DataTable();
          da_projekt.Fill(dt_projekt);
          cb_projekt_id.DataSource = dt_projekt.DefaultView;
          cb_projekt_id.ValueMember = "projekt_id";
          cb_projekt_id.DisplayMember = "name_of_projekt";
          conn.Close();
      }
 }
```

When i select 13.10.2011 i get error. Date is recognised as MM.dd.yyyy. I tried everything (all in comments and many more). Yust don't find a solution.

Comment: 16 can not be **MM**, by default when you hover any variable `.ToString()` of that method is called, in your case it is `DateTime`, depending upon your machine setting it is showing in `MM.dd.yyyy`. What is the data type of `odr[1]`?

Comment: odr[1] is object, value is {16.10.2011 0:00:00} in excel fields are date `dd.MM.yyyy`

Comment: Secondly you don't have to worry about how it is displayed in SQL, when you will retrieve it the date will be same as what you have stored. After that you can call `.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to get date in `dd.MM.yyyy` format but this will be `string` not `DateTime`

Comment: That is the problem: display in SQL Server. SQL Server thinks that i insert 16 as a month and 10 as a day. So when i search by the day in other forms i get error when date_of_hours exceded 12.10.2011 (13.10.2011 - get error).

Comment: In that case you might be writing incorrect query in that form, can you post code for the same.

Comment: When you read the date string from dropdown, convert it using `DateTime.ParseExact("13.10.2011", "dd.MM.yyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment. your date value is stored as `Date` in SQL. So when you store date in SQL it will remain date only, and when you retrieve it you will get date object directly. In SQL, it might be displayed as `MM.dd.yyyy` it doesn't matter.

When you will read this data from SQL, you will get `DateTime` object, on this if you do `.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` you will get in `dd.MM.yyyy` format. You can use any format on `DateTime` object, read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I postet all my code. Have you got any suggestion about where to put `.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, because i still think that the problem is in `INSERT` into SQL Server

Comment: See when you read info from SQL, don't do anything, bind it directly to the drop down, but when you hit `cb_datum_SelectedIndexChanged`, inside that `string date1 = drvProjekt["date_of_hours"].ToString(); DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Still no luck. Still says: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`, in line `DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: And what is the value of `date1`?

Comment: `date1` value is `"1.10.2011 0:00:00"` but date2 is `{1.1.0001 0:00:00}

Comment: Do this `date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "d.MM.yyyy h:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: 10.12.2011 then i get an error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` but values of date1 and date2 are correctly written

Comment: Either choose `1.10.2011 0:00:00` or `10.12.2011`, for your last comment this works `DateTime.ParseExact("10.12.2011", "d.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Sorry 12.10.2011 error, it still think that 12 is the month. But in date2 details is day 12 month 10 !! Hmmmm, is possible that `date_of_start, date_of_end` are wrong? Could't be, cause if i insert date_of_start value 10.16.2011 i get error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7229/discussion-between-amar-palsapure-and-janolmajti)

Comment: No. in my last example 10.12.2011, date is 10th of Dec 2011.

Comment: In my SQL Server it shows dd.MM.yyyy. In my Combobox it shows dd.MM.yyyy. But when i do `WHERE date_of_start < '" + date2 + "' AND date_of_end` it recognised as MM.d.yyyy and MM.dd.yyyy (13.10.2011)

Comment: Don't worry what SQL shows, internally it is storing it correctly.

Comment: thanks for help, appreciate it. Try to write it again in different way, we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, just replace "." with "/" in the excel file and format the cell as dd/mmm/yyyy

Answer (score 3):

Excel natively keeps dates as days since some date I do not remember as a floating point value. The important thing is that this matches DateTime.ToOADate().

We read dates from excel files as a floating point value and then use DateTime.ToOADate().

Comment: In your case it insert only to 10.12.2011 (MM.dd.yyyy) format and then i get an error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

Answer (score 3):

You use `CONVERT` the wrong way. Database-side, you convert a datetime to a string (varchar), and then you have to rely on build-in type conversions to get a datetime again. You should do it the other way around. If in c# you convert the datetime to a string with a specified format and convert it to a datetime with a matching style database-side nothing can go wrong.

When you use `CONVERT` the date part should match the *style* you use (in your case 104). Use this in your sql:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, @date_of_hours, 104)
```

and

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@date_of_hours", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
    string.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", odr[1])
```

Comment: it insert only to 10.12.2011 ,then i get an error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` (10.13.2011)

Comment: Ok, but now the problem is reduced to getting datetime values in your odr[1] column. I don't understand why that's not the case if the format in excel is "Date". What excel version do you use? 8.0 suggests excel '97, but "xlsx" suggests at least Excel 2007 (v. 12).

Comment: I use excel 2010, cells are date and if i change the date format in excel, it changes correctly (i mean date format). Yeah i know it's bugging me for 2 days

Comment: But then I think you should use an other connection string: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, and Extended Properties=Excel 12.0. Using this I always get datetime values from excel columns with format "Date" (irrespective of the display in excel).

Comment: Are you sure that _all_ values in the date_of_hours column in your sheet have the "Date" format?

Comment: Super sure! Checked again. I'm thinking that i will start this code all over again, just this part. My excel is im my language. Can this effect on data?

Comment: I have excel with Dutch as default language. I get datetimes.

Comment: How do you insert from excel to DB? Like me or some other way?